# drawing a dynamic dot on an image

Tags: android, google-maps

I am writing an indoor positioning application for android and I need to show a dot on an image (map) which its position on that map is continuously updating during the program. What methods should I use for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Create a subclass of `ImageView` so you can set your map as the `ImageView` contents; then override the `onDraw()` method, which will provide you with a `Canvas` that you can draw anything you like on.  Here's some pseudocode to illustrate the idea:

```
public class DotImageView extends ImageView {

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        //Call super for default behavior (draw the image first)
        super.onDraw(c);

        //Then draw your dot anywhere you like
        c.drawCircle(...);
    }

}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You want to show 3D dot on map (from your question).

So, i suggest you to draw overlays on map by extending overlay class and as location updates draw new dot image with adding new overlay to list of overlays in draw method. write method which which supplies updated location to draw method which gets exact point using GeoPoint & Point classes you can use to draw exact location from lat, long. [Link to hlep](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android).
If helpful appreciate..